# How to make jQuery find the .owl-video-frame class in Owl Carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have a few videos in a carousel, with items entered like this:

```
    <div id="owl4" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
       <div class="owl-item-container video-aspect-16-9" data-aspect="1.7777778">         
            <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dhn6yCygS8"></a>
            <div class="owl-text-container">
                <h2>This video is 19:9</h2>
                <a class="owl-image-link" href="#">
                    <p>Some text.</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item-container video-aspect-4-3" data-aspect="1.333333">
            <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S03UOkb9zU4"></a>
            <div class="owl-text-container">
             <a class="owl-image-link" href="#">
                <h2>This video is 4/3.</h2>
                <p>Some text.</p>
            </a>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The script is like this:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#owl4').owlCarousel({
                items:1,
                margin:0,
                dots:true,
                video:true,
                onPlayVideo: videoSize
            });

            function videoSize(event){
                var video = $(document).find(".owl-video-frame");
                console.log(video);
            }
        });
```

The carousel works. But I am trying to get jQuery to find the `div` with the class `.owl-video-frame` that Owl Carousel 2 adds when the video play symbol is clicked.

With the above code I can make iQuery find `.owl-video-wrapper`, which is the parent of `.owl-video-frame` and also added by Owl Carousel. If I do this and `console.log` I can see `.owl-video-frame` in the list of `.owl-video-wrapper` children. But I still can't make jQuery find `.owl-video-frame` or the `iframe` containing the youtube video.

I have the same problem if I use `event` instead of `document`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I can target the video that is currently playing because jQuery will find `.owl-item.active`. However, the problem is that jQuery won't find anything after `.owl-video-wrapper` so I can't 'get to' `.owl-video-frame`.

**EDIT2**
This is the entire code once the play button is clicked on the first video and the extra `div`s and `iframe` have been added by Owl Carousel:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Owl Slider</title>
    <link href="scripts/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="scripts/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="scripts/stuff-style-carousel-3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/owl.carousel.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Video with&nbsp;100% width of the browser window and maintains its aspect ratio</h1>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag" id="owl4">
        <div class="owl-stage-outer">
            <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0s; width: 1196px;">
                <div class="owl-item active owl-video-playing" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dhn6yCygS8" style="width: 598px;">
                    <div class="owl-item-container video-aspect-16-9" data-aspect="1.7777778">
                        <div class="owl-video-wrapper">
                            <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dhn6yCygS8" style="display: none;"></a>
                            <div class="owl-video-frame">
                                <iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="251" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1Dhn6yCygS8?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;v=1Dhn6yCygS8" width="100%"></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div class="owl-video-play-icon"></div>
                            <div class="owl-video-tn" style="opacity:1;background-image:url(//img.youtube.com/vi/1Dhn6yCygS8/hqdefault.jpg)"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="owl-text-container">
                            <h2>This video is 19:9</h2><a class="owl-image-link" href="#">
                            <p>Some text.</p></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S03UOkb9zU4" style="width: 598px;">
                    <div class="owl-item-container video-aspect-4-3" data-aspect="1.333333">
                        <div class="owl-video-wrapper">
                            <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S03UOkb9zU4" style="display: none;"></a>
                            <div class="owl-video-play-icon"></div>
                            <div class="owl-video-tn" style="opacity:1;background-image:url(//img.youtube.com/vi/S03UOkb9zU4/hqdefault.jpg)"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="owl-text-container">
                            <a class="owl-image-link" href="#">
                            <h2>This video is 4/3.</h2>
                            <p>Some text.</p></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-nav disabled">
            <button class="owl-prev" role="presentation" type="button"><span aria-label="Previous">‹</span></button><button class="owl-next" role="presentation" type="button"><span aria-label="Next">›</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-dots">
            <button class="owl-dot active" role="button"><span></span></button><button class="owl-dot" role="button"><span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                   $('#owl4').owlCarousel({
                       items:1,
                       margin:0,
                       dots:true,
                       video:true,
                       onPlayVideo: videoSize
                   });

                   function videoSize(event){
                       var video = $(document).find(".owl-video-frame");
                       console.log(video);
                   }
               });


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see the `owl-video-frame` class anywhere in your html

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each of your `owl-video` containers in order to get the individual videos.

```
$('.owl-video').each( function() {
    var video = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(video);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can target the video that is currently playing because jQuery will find `.owl-item.active`. However, the problem is that jQuery won't find anything after .owl-video-wrapper

Comment: maybe I'm blind but I don't see either `owl-item active` and `owl-item frame` classes in your html.

Comment: No, your not blind. `div`s with these classes are added by Owl Carousel and so are not in the code I wrote.

Comment: Can't troubleshoot if we can't see the code. Use inspect in your browser to get that and add it.

Comment: I have added the code once Owl Carousel has added the extra divs etc.